# Displaying the results of a Mongoose query to pug

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

I have the following code.

events.js model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    eventType: String,
    attendees: { type: Number, default: 0 }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('events', locationSchema)
```

index.js route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const ctrlMain = require('../controllers/main');
const mongojs = require('mongojs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Event = require('../models/events')

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://*****:*****@cluster0-myta3.mongodb.net/newintown?retryWrites=true&w=majority')


// get all events

router.get('/eventList', ctrlMain.eventList)
```

I have the following in my controller

// events list

```
const eventList = (req, res, next) => {
    Event.find()
    .exec()
    .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc);
        res.render('eventList', {
            title: 'New In Town',
            events: doc
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Everything in the collection logs to the console OK, so the query works, but I'm struggling to get it in to the PUG template. My template looks like this

```
block content
    each event in events
            p.mainText = event.eventType
```

The problem is that it just writes the words 'event.eventType'. How do I get it to display the eventType fields from the query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the equals sign next to the HTML element:

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/pacific202/pen/bGNEbLq) shows the issue:

```
- var test = 'hello world'
div = test
div= test
```

produces:

```
= test 
hello world
```